# autogen.sh not found installng Hercules

Tags: autoconf

I'm following [this guide](http://www.hercules-390.eu/hercinst.html) to install Hercules, and everything goes well up to step 3 of **Building from source - Linux and Mac OS X**, where I get these results:

```
hugolvc@HuLuVicaMacUbuntu:~/Downloads/mvs/hercules-3.13$ ./util/bldlvlck
This utility will check the level of various utilities needed to build
hercules. Checking is done against versions that are KNOWN to work.
This doesn't mean a build will NOT succeed with older versions
of the utilities, but will give a hint as to what package may need
an upgrade if the build ever fails with some odd reason.


OK  autoconf requires 2.5, found 2.71

OK  automake requires 1.9, found 1.16.5

OK  gawk requires 3.0, found 5.1.0

OK  gcc requires 3, found 11.4.0

OK  grep requires 1, found 3.7

OK  libiconv requires 1.8, found 2.35.0

OK  m4 requires 1.4.6, found 1.4.18

OK  make requires 3.79, found 4.3

OK  perl requires 5.6, found 5.34.0

OK  sed requires 3.02, found 4.8
```

The problem raises in the following step:

```
4. Generate the configure script:
./autogen.sh
```

It raises this error:

```
hugolvc@HuLuVicaMacUbuntu:~/Downloads/mvs/hercules-3.13$ ./autogen.sh
bash: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory
```

Do I have to install anything else to have this executable available?

Comment: @user68186 it was a typo, I actually used `./autogen.sh`

Comment: @user68186 done

Comment: @user68186 `ls: cannot access './autogen.sh': No such file or directory`

Comment: @user68186 it doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems like the downloaded gzip archive (they are like zip files) do not include this particular file. You will have to ask the developers of the app. Maybe they forgot to include it. Try skipping step 4 and go directly to step 5.

Comment: An autogen.sh script typically just runs a few autotools commands to generate .a configure script from the configure.ac template - you possibly don't need this step if a `./configure` file already exists

Comment: Also note that in **Step 7** you will need to use the command `sudo make install`, as the instruction says "install the program as root".